# Is there a way to extract data from calendar js(maybe)? python beautifulsoup selenium post calendar scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, calendar

I want to extract datas from the calendar in this website.
https://www.dreamplus.asia/event/list

If I click the  tags which are evnets or the day of the events in the calendar. Detail information of tag pops up on the right side of the calendar. As you can see this website is made of js (probably) (if you see the detailed page source)

Even though I've used selenium to click the tag which are days or the events, I couldn't find how to click those things. Any helps?

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
    import os
    import re
    import json
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import traceback
    from pprint import pprint 
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    def dreamplus():    
        options = Options()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='../../chromedriver.exe',         options=options)

        driver.get("https://www.dreamplus.asia/event/list")

        #driver = launchBrowser()
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        #Days = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*        [@id='calendar']/div[@class='fc-view-container']/div[@class='fc-view fc-month-view fc-basic-view']/table/tbody[@class='fc-body']/tr/td[@class='fc-widget-content']/div[@class='fc-scroller fc-day-grid-container']/div/div/div/table")
        Controllers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('fc-event-container')
        print(Controllers)
        for list in Controllers:
            print(list.text)

        driver.close()



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            dreamplus()
        except BaseException as e:
                    with open('dreamplus_error.log','wt') as f:
                            f.write(traceback.format_exc())
                            f.close()
```

I used find_elements_by_class_name to get 'fc-event-container' to get items But 'Controllers' is empty. probably because  it is js..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that if you attempt to go direct to `event` you get re-directed to homepage. So, you can either go to home package and click through to events, or simply do two `.get`s in a row. Note: you want the child `a` tags within the containers for clicking to update sidebar info.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.dreamplus.asia/')
d.get('https://www.dreamplus.asia/event/list')
events = WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fc-event-container a")))
events[2].click()  #example event click
```

---

Clicking through (slower):

```
d.get('https://www.dreamplus.asia/')
event_tabs = d.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Event')]")
event_tabs[0].click()
event_tabs[1].click()
events = WebDriverWait(d,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fc-event-container a")))
events[2].click()  #example event click
```